# Print state value with button click

Tags: reactjs

I created a component called CreateUserComponent to create a user. This component has a form to receive data from the user. I want to print this data I received from the user at the bottom of the form after the save button is pressed. How can I print these(identificationNumber, firstName_lastName, monthlyIncome, phoneNumber).

**CreateUserComponent.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import UserService from '../services/UserService';

class CreateUserComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            // step 2
            id: this.props.match.params.id,
            identificationNumber: '',
            firstName_lastName: '',
            monthlyIncome: '',
            phoneNumber: ''

        }
        this.changeidentificationNumberHandler = this.changeidentificationNumberHandler.bind(this);
        this.changefirstName_lastNameHandler = this.changefirstName_lastNameHandler.bind(this);
        this.changemonthlyIncomeHandler = this.changemonthlyIncomeHandler.bind(this);
        this.changephoneNumberHandler = this.changephoneNumberHandler.bind(this);
        this.saveUser = this.saveUser.bind(this);
    }

    
    saveUser = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let user = {identificationNumber: this.state.identificationNumber, firstName_lastName: this.state.firstName_lastName, monthlyIncome: this.state.monthlyIncome, phoneNumber: this.state.phoneNumber};
        console.log('user => ' + JSON.stringify(user));

    

    
        // step 3

            UserService.createUser(user).then(res =>{
                this.props.history.push('/kredibasvurusu');
                
                
            });
    }
    
    changeidentificationNumberHandler= (event) => {
        this.setState({identificationNumber: event.target.value});
    }

    changefirstName_lastNameHandler= (event) => {
        this.setState({firstName_lastName: event.target.value});
    }

    changemonthlyIncomeHandler= (event) => {
        this.setState({monthlyIncome: event.target.value});
    }

    changephoneNumberHandler= (event) => {
      this.setState({phoneNumber: event.target.value});
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <br></br>
                   <div className = "container">
                        <div className = "row">
                            <div className = "card col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-md-3">
                            <h3 className="text-center">Hemen Kredi Alın</h3>
                                <div className = "card-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <div className = "form-outline mb-4">
                                            <label> Tc kimlik numaraniz: </label>
                                            <input type="number" placeholder="Lütfen Tcnizi giriniz" name="identificationNumber" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.identificationNumber} onChange={this.changeidentificationNumberHandler}/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className = "form-outline mb-4">
                                            <label> Adınız Soyadınız: </label>
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Adınız Soyadınızı giriniz" name="firstName_lastName" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.firstName_lastName} onChange={this.changefirstName_lastNameHandler}/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className = "form-outline mb-4">
                                            <label> Aylık gelir: </label>
                                            <input type="number" placeholder="Aylık gelirinizi giriniz" name="monthlyIncome" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.monthlyIncome} onChange={this.changemonthlyIncomeHandler}/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className = "form-outline mb-4">
                                            <label> Telefon Numarası: </label>
                                            <input type="number" placeholder="Telefon Numaranızı girin" name="phoneNumber" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.phoneNumber} onChange={this.changephoneNumberHandler}/>
                                        </div>

                                        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.saveUser}>Kredi Başvurusu Yap</button>
                                    </form>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                   </div>
            </div>

    
        )
    }
}

export default CreateUserComponent
```

Comment: Why don't you read it from the `this.state`? Also, since you are already using class properties, you don't need to rebind them in your constructor, they are already bound to the class, choose 1 approach :)

Comment: I used this.state but I couldn't set it to print when the button is pressed.

Comment: Probably, because you redirect after successful save action :) Don't redirect, or use preserve log in your developer console

Comment: I removed the redirect and after saving I stay on the same page. but it prints with this.state when data is entered without pressing the button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting your updates in states, you can print them in this way

First create new state called isSaved and by default set it to false

```
this.state = {
            // step 2
            id: this.props.match.params.id,
            identificationNumber: '',
            firstName_lastName: '',
            monthlyIncome: '',
            phoneNumber: ''
            isSaved: false
        }
```

Second set it inside `saveUser` function

```
this.setState({isSaved: true});
```

And as last step check the render with this state

```
{ isSaved &&
    <div>
          <p>
            {this.state.identificationNumber}
          </p>
          <p>
            {this.state.firstName_lastName}
          </p>
          <p>
            {this.state.monthlyIncome}
          </p>
          <p>
            {this.state.phoneNumber}
          </p>
    </div> }
```

Comment: I did it this way but it shouldn't print without pressing the button

Comment: After save you can not use your states because you are redırecting to another page after succesfull save. You should pass them as props to another component or you can use them with redux so you can create global states and access them from other components

Comment: I removed the redirect and after saving I stay on the same page. How can I print these states after saving them?

Comment: I updated my answer, check it please @MustafaBulu